# Infinite loop mistake

Tags: python, loops

I'm having issues with this loop. I try to break the loop once the user write "S" or "n" but it doesn't do it.

```
user_input = ""
issue_num = 0
ISSUES = ["El motor o las cuchillas no arrancan", "La comida esta picada de manera desigual",
                "La comida esta picada muy fina o aguada", "Los alimentos se acumulan en la tapa",
                "La base del motor no se adhiere a la mesa", 'Tiene un mensaje de "ERR"',
                "Tiene una luz roja parapadeante"]
anoun_of_issues = len(ISSUES)

while user_input != "salir":
    print(ISSUES[issue_num])

    user_input = input('Pulsse "S" si es su inconveniente, pulse "n" si no lo es y escriba "salir" para salir... ')

    if user_input != "s" or user_input != "n":
        while user_input != "s" or user_input != "n":
            user_input = input('Pulsse "S" si es su inconveniente, pulse "n" si no lo es y escriba "salir" para salir... ')

    if user_input == "s":
        if issue_num == 0:
            pass
```

Comment: Think about it: if the user's input is  'S' it is then not 'N' and it will enter the first `if` statement - if the input is 'N' then it's not 'S' and will also enter the same statement.  You actually mean to say that if the input is not 'S' AND not 'N'...

Comment: `if user_input not in {"s", "n"}:`. Maybe you want to make it case insensitive, specially since your promp suggest "S" and "n": `if user_input.lower() not in {"s", "n"}:`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are using in your inner loop is `user_input != "s" or user_input != "n"`. This condition is always true because you are using `or`. The only way it could fail to be true is if `user_input` was somehow equal to `"s"` and `"n"` at the same time. Since that's not possible with a normal string, you keep looping forever.

To make the loop end when either `"s"` or `"n"` is entered, use `user_input != "s" and user_input != "n"`.